# Como realizar alteração em sequência de ordem com instrução SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulário onde exibo para o usuário algumas fases que um determinado contrato precisa respeitar, segue imagem do referido formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já fiz o `update` que realiza a alteração da ordem e está funcionando, minha dúvida é a seguinte, seguindo o exemplo da imagem que postei, como posso alterar a ordem 3 para 1 e a 1 para a ordem 3 no mesmo instante.

O código que faz o update sem essa rotina implementada é essa:

```
if ($_POST["Operacao"] == 'UpFaseObrigatoria') {

    $sql = "UPDATE `intranet_cocari`.`gerFaseObrigatoria` 
               SET `Ordem` = ? 
             WHERE `gerFaseObrigatoria`.`IdContrato` = ? 
               AND `gerFaseObrigatoria`.`IdTipoFase` = ?";

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) ){
        $stmt->bind_param(
            "iii",
            $_POST["Ordem"],
            $_POST["IdContrato"],           
            $_POST["IdTipoFase"]
        );

        if ($stmt->execute()){
            $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro atualizado com sucesso.";          
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na atualização dos dados: " . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
            $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
        }
    } else {
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na preparação dos dados: "  . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    }
}
```

Já consegui muita coisa com a ajuda do @Felipe Moraes, o código alterado de acordo com a sugestão ficou assim:

```
UPDATE
    gerFaseObrigatoria AS FaseObrigatoria
    JOIN gerFaseObrigatoria AS gerFaseObrigatoriaUp ON
           ( FaseObrigatoria.Ordem = ? AND gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem = 1 )
        OR ( FaseObrigatoria.Ordem = 1 AND gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem = ? )
SET
    FaseObrigatoria.Ordem = gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem,
    gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem = FaseObrigatoria.Ordem
WHERE   
    FaseObrigatoria.IdContrato = ? AND gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.IdContrato = ?
```

Copie e colei esse treco de código em meu `BD` e a alteração foi realizada com sucesso, mas ao aplicar em minha página o script me dá a mensagem que a alteração foi feita, mas a mesma não está sendo executada.
Creio que estou cometendo o erro no momento da substituição do `bind_param`, o código está assim:

```
if ($_POST["Operacao"] == 'UpFaseObrigatoria') {


    $sql = "UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria AS FaseObrigatoria
                JOIN gerFaseObrigatoria AS gerFaseObrigatoriaUp ON
                           ( FaseObrigatoria.Ordem = ? AND gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem = 1 )
                        OR ( FaseObrigatoria.Ordem = 1 AND gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem = ? )
                SET
                    FaseObrigatoria.Ordem = gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem,
                    gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem = FaseObrigatoria.Ordem
                WHERE   
                    FaseObrigatoria.IdContrato = ? AND gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.IdContrato = ? ";

    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) ){
        $stmt->bind_param(
            "iiii",     
            $_POST["Ordem"],    
            $_POST["Ordem"],        
            $_POST["IdContrato"],
            $_POST["IdContrato"]
        );

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro atualizado com sucesso.";          
            $stmt->close();
        }else{
            $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na atualização dos dados: " . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
            $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
        }
    }else{
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na preparação dos dados: "  . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A técnica para isso é fazer um join para obter as 2 linhas a serem trocas e depois fazer um simples update, veja:

```
UPDATE
    tabela AS tabela1
JOIN 
    tabela AS tabela2 ON ( tabela1.ordem = 1 AND tabela2.ordem = 3 )
SET
    tabela1.ordem = tabela2.ordem,
    tabela2.ordem = tabela1.ordem
```

Se for preciso aplicar apenas a um determinado contrato, basta adicionar a cláusula `where`, por exemplo, trocar a ordem apenas para o contrato 35:

```
WHERE
    troca1.contrato = 35 AND troca2.contrato = 35
```

O exemplo acima não condiz com a estrutura real da sua tabela, deve ser adaptado conforme a sua necessidade.

Você pode ler mais sobre o assunto aqui: http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/swap-values-in-2-rows-sql/

**Update:**

A sua variável `$sql` ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE
        gerFaseObrigatoria AS FaseObrigatoria
    JOIN 
        gerFaseObrigatoria AS gerFaseObrigatoriaUp 
    ON
        (FaseObrigatoria.Ordem = ? AND gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem = ? )
    SET
        FaseObrigatoria.Ordem = gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem,
        gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.Ordem = FaseObrigatoria.Ordem
    WHERE   
        FaseObrigatoria.IdContrato = ? AND                
        gerFaseObrigatoriaUp.IdContrato = ? "
;
```

O método `bind_param` ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$stmt->bind_param(
    "iiii",     
    $_POST["Ordem_1"], //aqui é a ordem atual do 1º registro          
    $_POST["Ordem_2"], //aqui é a ordem atual do 2º registro        
    $_POST["IdContrato"],
    $_POST["IdContrato"]
);
```

Repare que modifiquei o `$_POST`, passou a existir o `Ordem_1` e `Ordem_2`, ou seja, será necessário informar a ordem dos 2 registros que devem ser trocados. Se desejar trocar o registro com a ordem 2 com o registro com a ordem 3, da forma como você fez só poderia trocar o registro com a ordem 1 com outro qualquer.

Comment: Olá @Felipe Moraes a sua dica foi excelente, montei minha query e aplique a mesma em meu BD para testar e funcionou perfeitamente, mas agora, quando tento jogar o mesmo script no exemplo que postei não está dando certo? Creio ser no momento da substituição do bind_param, alguma sugestão?

Comment: @adventistapr como ficou o seu código com a alteração? Pode postar? Mas não apague o código da pergunta, se não fica sem contexto.

Comment: Olá @Filipe Moraes, mas como posso postar? No mesmo post da pergunta ou um novo?

Comment: @adventistapr alterei a resposta adicionando como o código PHP deveria ficar. Veja se ajuda, se não posta aqui nos comentários a sua dificuldade.

Answer (score 3):

## Mudança na tabela

Você está passando uma dificuldade por não ter um identificador unico para cada registro. Recomendo adicionar na sua tabela o campo `id` e marcar como `auto increment` assim você terá uma chave primária que identificará o registro.

Sua tabela deverá ficar assim:

```
- Id          INT(11)     NOT NULL    UNSIGNED    AUTO_INCREMENT
- IdContrato  INT(11)     NOT NULL    UNSIGNED
- IdTipoFase  INT(11)     NOT NULL    UNSIGNED
- Ordem       INT(11)     NOT NULL    UNSIGNED
```

## Formulário

No seu formulário basta adicionar um campo para passar o `id` dos registros que quer alterar.

```
<input type="hidden" value"{id}" name="id">
```

**Atenção**

Se deseja que seu código identifique dois registros diferentes, é necessário nomear os campos de forma que permita enviar mais registros.

Por exemplo utilizando o código

```
<input type="hidden" value"1" name="id">
<input type="hidden" value"2" name="id">
```

O valor de `$_POST['id']` será sempre o valor do último campo com esse nome em seu HTML. No exemplo acima o valor obtido será `2`.

Para obter vários registro utilizando um nome apenas para campo, adicione `[]` na frente, pois assim o PHP irá tratar como um array. Exemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" value"1" name="id[]">
<input type="hidden" value"2" name="id[]">
```

Isso irá retornar em `$_POST['id']` o valor `array (1,2)`.

```
echo `$_POST['id'][0]`; // Imprime: 1
echo `$_POST['id'][1]`; // Imprime: 2

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
    echo 'Id: ' . $id . "\n";
}
// Imprime 
// Id: 1
// Id: 2
```

Lembrando que os índices de um array começam de 0;

## Alterando diretamente a posição entre dois registros

No caso de alterar a posição de um pelo outro basta recuperar os registros utilizando os IDs informados e atualizar as ordens.

Se colocou um índice que indique que a relação entre os campos `IdContrato` e `Ordem` é única, será necessário colocar um deles em uma posição inválida, isto é, que não exista no banco de dados, como `-1` atualizar o outro e em seguida atualizar o primeiro com a posição certa.

```sql
-- {id1} : Id do primeiro registro
-- {nova_ordem1} : é a ordem que o primeiro registro irá ficar

-- {id2} : Id do segundo registro
-- {nova_ordem2} : é a ordem que o segundo registro irá ficar

UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = "{nova_ordem1}"
WHERE `Id` = "{id1}";

UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = "{nova_ordem2}"
WHERE `Id` = "{id2}";

-- Caso possua o índice unique

UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = "-1"
WHERE `Id` = "{id1}";

UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = "{nova_ordem2}"
WHERE `Id` = "{id2}";

UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = "{nova_ordem1}"
WHERE `Id` = "{id1}";
```

## Alterando a posição de um registro específico para qualquer posição acima.

Se deseja que o registro que atualmente está na ordem `10` passe para a `2`, basta obter o registro que deseja alterar do banco de dados para saber a atual posição, em seguida atualize todos os registros de ordem menor adicionando 1, e em seguida atualize o registro que realmente quer alterar.

Seu SQL deverá ficar mais ou menos assim

```sql
-- {nova_ordem} : é a ordem que o registro irá ficar
-- {ordem_atual} : é a ordem que o registro está antes de iniciar a alteração

UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = `ordem` + 1
WHERE `IdContrato` = "55"
AND `ordem` >= "{nova_ordem}"
AND `ordem` < "{ordem_atual}"
ORDER BY `IdContrato_id`, `ordem`;

UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = "{nova_ordem}"
WHERE `Id` = "{id}";
```

Observe que a atualização se limita entre uma faixa, para garantir que nenhum registro mude sua ordem sem necessidade.

## Alterando a posição de um registro específico para qualquer posição abaixo.

Para mudar para uma ordem de valor maior, repita o processo anterior invertendo os sinais.

```sql
UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = `ordem` - 1
WHERE `IdContrato` = "55"
AND `ordem` <= "{nova_ordem}"
AND `ordem` > "{ordem_atual}"
ORDER BY `IdContrato_id`, `ordem`;

UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
SET `ordem` = "{nova_ordem}"
WHERE `Id` = "{id}";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($_POST["Operacao"] == 'UpFaseObrigatoria') {

// 1º Criar a "ordem" oposta
    $o1 = $_POST['Ordem'] === 1 ? 3 : 1;
    $o2 = $o1 === 1 ? 3 : 1;

// 2º Modificar a ordem do "outro" registro
    $sql = 'UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
               SET Ordem = :o1
             WHERE Ordem = :o2';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([':o1'=>$o1, ':o2'=>$o2]);

// 3º Inserir a nova ordem no registro indicado (contrato + tipo)
    $sql = 'UPDATE gerFaseObrigatoria
               SET Ordem = :o2
             WHERE IdContrato = :contrato
               AND IdTipoFase = :tipo';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $res = $stmt->execute([':o2'=>$o2,
                           ':contrato'=>$_POST['idContrato'], 
                           ':tipo'=>$_POST['IdTipoFase']
                          ]);

    if($res){
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro atualizado com sucesso.";          
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na atualização dos dados: "
                           .$stmt->error.". Verifique.";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    }
} else {
    $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na preparação dos dados: "
                       .$stmt->error.". Verifique.";
    $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
}
```

}

Testei aqui em uma simulação e funcionou!

Tenho uma pergunta: Essa "ORDEM" é só para apresentar ordenado na tela?
Se sim, não precisaria desse registro no banco - a ordenação poderia se dar na "visualização" apenas, evitando tanto trabalho.